# Update the default port for apache tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I have multiple installation of standalone apache tomcat web servers and would like to run them parallely. However, I am facing port conflict. Please point me where I can update the port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the default **port (8080)** in `<tomcat-install-dir>/conf/server.xml` under connector xml element. Replace it with something like **8081**.